# GPS and Wifi are not enabled but isProviderEnabled is returning always true

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

In this case I use GPS,Network as a Provider, I try walking inside the building but seem like it doesn't find the location.. So, Why isProviderEnabled return true? Anyway, What is the way that i should implement ?
This is my code :

```
public class GPSTraker extends Service implements LocationListener {


private final Context context ;
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled= false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location;
double latitude ;
double longitude ;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60 ;
private LocationManager locationManager;
public GPSTraker(Context context){
    this.context=context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation(){
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            //No providers
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
          /*  if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    }
                }

            }*/
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                            this
                    );
                    Log.d("GPS", "GPS");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Exeception getLocation",e.toString());
    }
    return location;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}
public boolean canGetLocation(){
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
public void showSettingAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is setting");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();

}
/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTraker.this);
    }
}
```

}

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns true because it's enabled. You don't ask if it's able calculate your position. To get updates when your location is changed use onLocationChanged().